# Average Temperature through the day in R

Tags: r, graph

I've got a data set that I collected over the summer where I collected the air temperature and also the internal temperature of different snakes at roughly 2 hour intervals throughout the day, looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bQzK.png)

or in R Code:

```
dput(Temps)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1687651200, 1687651200, 1687651200, 
1687651200, 1687651200, 1687737600, 1687737600, 1687737600, 1687737600, 
1687824000, 1687824000, 1687824000, 1687824000, 1688169600, 1688169600, 
1688169600, 1688169600, 1688688000, 1688688000, 1688688000, 1688688000, 
1688774400, 1688774400, 1688774400, 1688860800, 1688860800, 1688860800, 
1688860800, 1688947200, 1688947200, 1688947200, 1688947200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(-2209038660, -2209034580, 
-2209027380, -2209020540, -2209013940, -2209034820, -2209027800, 
-2209021020, -2209013940, -2209035000, -2209028220, -2209021200, 
-2209014000, -2209031700, -2209026360, -2209019340, -2209013040, 
-2209031700, -2209026480, -2209018800, -2209012980, -2209024740, 
-2209018680, -2209013340, -2209032720, -2209027380, -2209019100, 
-2209013580, -2209034520, -2209027440, -2209020000, -2209013520
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Air Temp` = c(22, 
23, 21, 18, 19, 18, 19, 20, 19, 17, 19, 19, 19, 17, 16, 18, 17, 
22, 23, 24, 24, 22, 21, 18, 21, 21, 20, 20, 16, 16, 19, 19), 
    `Snake Temp` = c(27, 30.5, 27, 27, 21.5, 27, 30.5, 30.5, 
    27, 30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 30.5, 
    30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    27)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

I want to make a graph that shows the average temperature of both the snakes and the air throughout the day, with error bars as polygons

My supervisor has shown me what he wants the graph to look like to compare them but I'm having no luck producing anything even similar.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *error bars as polygons*? Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Average temperature how?  Average of all measurements or the average of the high and low (this is how the weather is reported)?

Comment: @Friede - pretty sure he means error envelope, which would be `geom_ribbon()` in `ggplot2`

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic approach intended to get you started.
Among other things, due to the small amount of data confidence intervals cp. `?ggplot2::geom_smooth` (see `se`-argument) does not seem appropriate in my opinion. I wasn't able to identify more than one snake.

We first repair your datetime data and floor that to the nearest hour. Then, we switch to long format, create groups (`Air`, `Snake`), and calculate averages for different `Times`.

**Approach**

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df |>
  mutate(Datetime = floor_date(as.POSIXct(paste(
    format(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), format(Time, "%H:%M:%S")), tz = "UTC"), unit = "hour"),
    Time = format(Datetime, "%H:%M:%S")) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(`Air Temp`, `Snake Temp`),
                      names_to = "Group", 
                      values_to = "Temp") |>
  mutate(Group = gsub("Temp", "", Group)) |>
  reframe(mTemp = mean(Temp, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(Time, Group)) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = mTemp, x = Time, group = Group)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Group)) + # alternatively:
  # geom_smooth(aes(colour = Group), 
  #            method = 'loess', formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE) + 
  labs(y = "Mean Temperature [°C]",
       x = "",
       colour = "Temperature of") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**Edit**
per @LTyrone's comment:

```r
rib = 
  df |>
  mutate(Datetime = floor_date(as.POSIXct(paste(
    format(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"), format(Time, "%H:%M:%S")), tz = "UTC"), unit = "hour"),
    Time = format(Datetime, "%H:%M:%S")) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(`Air Temp`, `Snake Temp`),
                      names_to = "Group", 
                      values_to = "Temp") |>
  mutate(Group = trimws(gsub("Temp", "", Group))) |>
  reframe(mTemp = mean(Temp, na.rm = TRUE),
          maxT = max(Temp, na.rm = TRUE),
          minT = min(Temp, na.rm = TRUE), 
          .by = c(Time, Group))

rib |>
  ggplot(aes(y = mTemp, x = Time, group = Group, fill = Group,
             ymin = minT, ymax = maxT)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .5) +
  labs(y = "min/max/mean temp [°C]",
       x = "time") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
df = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1687651200, 1687651200, 1687651200, 
                                       1687651200, 1687651200, 1687737600, 1687737600, 1687737600, 1687737600, 
                                       1687824000, 1687824000, 1687824000, 1687824000, 1688169600, 1688169600, 
                                       1688169600, 1688169600, 1688688000, 1688688000, 1688688000, 1688688000, 
                                       1688774400, 1688774400, 1688774400, 1688860800, 1688860800, 1688860800, 
                                       1688860800, 1688947200, 1688947200, 1688947200, 1688947200), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                              "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(-2209038660, -2209034580, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209027380, -2209020540, -2209013940, -2209034820, -2209027800, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209021020, -2209013940, -2209035000, -2209028220, -2209021200, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209014000, -2209031700, -2209026360, -2209019340, -2209013040, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209031700, -2209026480, -2209018800, -2209012980, -2209024740, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209018680, -2209013340, -2209032720, -2209027380, -2209019100, 
                                                                                                                                                            -2209013580, -2209034520, -2209027440, -2209020000, -2209013520
                                                                                                              ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Air Temp` = c(22, 
                                                                                                                                                                                23, 21, 18, 19, 18, 19, 20, 19, 17, 19, 19, 19, 17, 16, 18, 17, 
                                                                                                                                                                                22, 23, 24, 24, 22, 21, 18, 21, 21, 20, 20, 16, 16, 19, 19), 
                    `Snake Temp` = c(27, 30.5, 27, 27, 21.5, 27, 30.5, 30.5, 
                                     27, 30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 30.5, 
                                     30.5, 30.5, 30.5, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
                                     27)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                   -32L))
```